# Segmentation Fault C++, after parentheses operator

Tags: segmentation-fault, coredump, parentheses

I have a class A that override the parentheses operator. 
The following code works:

```
int main(){
     ..
     A a;
     cout << a({0.5});
     ..
}
```

While the following code doesn't work

```
A fun(){
     ..
     A a;
     return a;
     ..
}
int main(){
     ..
     A a = fun();
     cout << a({0.5});
}
```

When I execute this second code, I have the following error:

```
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can't understand why.

EDIT:

this is the overriding of the operator:

```
virtual arma::vec operator()(const InputC& input) override
{
    const arma::vec& x = params.normalizationF->normalize(Base::phi(input));
    forwardComputation(x);
    return params.normalizationO->restore(h.back());
}
```

This is the constructor:

```
FFNeuralNetwork_(Features_<InputC, denseOutput>& phi, unsigned int neurons,
                 unsigned int outputs) :
    ParametricRegressor(phi, outputs), BatchRegressor_<InputC, arma::vec, denseOutput>(phi, outputs)
{
    layerFunction.push_back(new Sigmoid());
    layerFunction.push_back(new Linear());

    layerNeurons.push_back(neurons);
    layerNeurons.push_back(outputs);

    setupNetwork();
}
```

And actually:

```
 typedef FFNeuralNetwork_<arma::vec> FFNeuralNetwork;
```

Where FFNeuralNetwork was the class A that I used in the example.

Here the actual  working code:

```
BasisFunctions basisPlane_ = IdentityBasis::generate(1);
DenseFeatures phiPlane_(basisPlane_);
FFNeuralNetwork planeNet(phiPlane_, 10, 1);
cout << planeNet({0.5});
```

Here  the  not working code:

```
FFNeuralNetwork createNetwork(..){
    BasisFunctions basisPlane_ = IdentityBasis::generate(1);
    DenseFeatures phiPlane_(basisPlane_);

    FFNeuralNetwork planeNet(phiPlane_, 10, 1);
    return planeNet;
}
..
FFNeuralNetwork net = createNetwork(..);
cout << net({0.5});
```

Comment: We're going to have to see the code for `class A` to figure this one out.

Comment: it is very long, do you think it is enough if I post just the overriding of the parenthesis operator?

Comment: Yes, do trim the code down to the relevant parts. I think the constructors could also be interesting in addition to the parenthesis operator.

Comment: I think now I added enough. I hope this code is understandable.

Answer (score 2):

In this bit of code you're passing a local variable `phiPlane_` by reference:

```
FFNeuralNetwork createNetwork(..){
    BasisFunctions basisPlane_ = IdentityBasis::generate(1);
    DenseFeatures phiPlane_(basisPlane_);

    FFNeuralNetwork planeNet(phiPlane_, 10, 1); // <- HERE
    return planeNet;
}

FFNeuralNetwork net = createNetwork(..);
cout << net({0.5});
```

Once the function returns the object that was passed by reference no longer exists so no code should access it after that. It may or may not be OK depending on what happens in `ParametricRegressor(phi, outputs)`, but it seems a bit dubious to me and could explain your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to C++. Why do you say that phiPlane no longer exist after the return? What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: The `phiPlane_` object only exists as a local (stack) variable in the function and once the function returns the object is destroyed and no longer valid. If you pass a reference (pointer) to it to another place and it tries to access the object after it's gone, bad things will happen.

Comment: Okay... so how can I fix this problem? should I use global variable for phiPlane? or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: It's difficult for me to give you a good suggestion as to how to fix it because I haven't seen the entirety of your code, but depending on the types of the objects you could pass actual instances instead of references (might not be what you want), allocate on the heap using `new` (but then you'll have to remember to `delete` it when you're done), or (perhaps best way) move to smart pointers such as `std::shared:ptr`.

Comment: If I understood correctly:  
    DenseFeatures* phiPlane_ = new DenseFeatures(basisPlane_);

    FFNeuralNetwork planeNet(*phiPlane_, 10, 1); // <- HERE
    return planeNet;

Comment: @Samuele: That should be `planeNet(*phiPlane_, ...)`. And don't forget to `delete` it when you're done! Smart pointers would take care of this for you with automatic reference counting.

Comment: Okay the code actually works! Thankyou very much. I have been more or less 5 hours on this. Thanks again :)